# Pgfplots surface looks "wiry"

Tags: pgfplots

I've plotted a function from some values, given in the form:

```
x,y,z
-2.4,-2.4,0.00208966369454526
-2.3,-2.4,0.00245568047497186
-2.2,-2.4,0.00284901821144199
-2.1,-2.4,0.00326424484110634
-2,-2.4,0.00369478959101684
-1.9,-2.4,0.00413324571684902
-1.8,-2.4,0.00457174861531703
-1.7,-2.4,0.00500239752919971
-1.6,-2.4,0.00541768332000374
-1.5,-2.4,0.005810883691126
-1.4,-2.4,0.00617639102950998
-1.3,-2.4,0.00650994613105532
-1.2,-2.4,0.0068087622314587
-1.1,-2.4,0.00707153627611177
-1,-2.4,0.00729835639420583
-0.9,-2.4,0.00749052445419115
-0.8,-2.4,0.00765031919830823
-0.7,-2.4,0.00778072823782364
-0.6,-2.4,0.0078851762449041
-0.5,-2.4,0.00796727266169779
-0.4,-2.4,0.00803059618622074
-0.3,-2.4,0.00807852634842078
-0.2,-2.4,0.00811412573961708
-0.0999999999999996,-2.4,0.00814007074426613
4.44089209850063e-16,-2.4,0.00815862445567777
0.1,-2.4,0.00817164300839456
...
```

This is how I create the plot:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf]
    table [col sep=comma]{dat.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Plot created using code given]=======

I would like it to look more like this (taken from the pgfplots manual):

[image: Goal]

That is, I'd like it to be filled in and not wiry.